# Java Thread instantiation with incorrect variables

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to use multithreading to break down a large block of processing data into smaller chunks.
The problem I am having is that my threads aren't running against their specified portion of the data space.

**For example:**

> thread-2 should process range of 0 - 1000
>
> thread-3 should process range of 1001 - 2000

When I call my new threads back to back i get:

> thread-2 = 0 - 1000
>
> thread-3 = 0 - 1000

When I add a Thread `sleep(3000)` in between the two thread calls i get:

> thread-2 = 0 - 1000
>
> thread-3 = 0 - 2000

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and would really appreciate some guidance.

Note on Snippits below, I abbreviated the above numbers actual call range in **example** below is

> 1,000,000 - 1,001,000 and 1,001,001 - 1,002,000

Snippet from main method detailing thread call:

```
        try {
        int start = 1000000;
        int end = 1001000;
        new Thread(new MyThread(start, end, PUBLIC_INVALID_LIST)).start();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        start = 1001001;
        end = 1002000;
        new Thread(new MyThread(start, end, PUBLIC_INVALID_LIST)).start();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
```

Snippet from MyThread which extends Thread
This details how I am passing params from the main method through to the `run()` method:

```
//variables to pass from constructor to run()
private int startIndex;
private int endIndex;
private ArrayList PUBLIC_INVALID_LIST;

MyThread(int startIndex, int endIndex, ArrayList PUBLIC_INVALID_LIST) {

    this.startIndex = startIndex;
    this.endIndex = endIndex;
    this.PUBLIC_INVALID_LIST = PUBLIC_INVALID_LIST;

}//end of initializer

public void run() {
```

Comment: well from what you ve posted i can imagine that `MyThread` is reordering the things inside the mutable `ArrayList PUBLIC_INVALID_LIST` when you are calling `thread.start()`. If you could post how the thread is manipulating the arraylist's data. but again doesnt make sense that with the `Thread.sleep()` works properly. Also as a second tryout , break the list with the `list.subList(from, to)` method instead of passing the whole list.

Comment: @AntJavaDev The goal of the program is to look through a list of paths and identify any that no longer exist. Any path that no longer exists has its path_id written via SP to a table. 'ArrayList PUBLIC_INVALID_LIST' is the return of an SQL query to retrieve all previously observed paths that no longer exist prior to launching the Threads, and is not modified by the Threads.  Each thread does its own SQL query to retrieve path_ids in the range startIndex to endIndex. And then filters that list to remove any path_id in 'PUBLIC_INVALID_LIST'

Comment: I don't see anything that stands out in the code you've shared so far. If you could share more of your code such as the `run` method of your `MyThread` class that would be helpful. Also, is there a reason you're not simply storing your data in a queue and pulling down items as you process them?

Answer (score 0):

still not sure what the issue was with the variable pass in, but I got an alternate pass in method to work using int[]

```
int sizeSet = (max /100000) + 1;//max is highest path_id value
    int[] start_range = new int[sizeSet];
    int[] end_range = new int[sizeSet];
    start_range[0] = 1;//first possible path_id
    end_range[0] = 100000;//end point of first possible range
    int rangeIndex = 1;//create counter for while loop
    while(rangeIndex < sizeSet){
        start_range[rangeIndex] = start_range[rangeIndex - 1] + 100000;
        end_range[rangeIndex] = end_range[rangeIndex - 1] + 100000;
        ++ rangeIndex;
    }//end range setting while block
    rangeIndex = 0;//reset index counter
    while(rangeIndex < sizeSet){
        new Thread(new MyThread(start_range[rangeIndex], end_range[rangeIndex], PUBLIC_INVALID_LIST)).start();
        ++ rangeIndex;
    }
```